# iOS issues working with nested frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, dependency-management

I've got a project with the following project decencies setup:

```
Main App 
    --> UIFramework (own framework)
        --> CoreFramework (own framework)
            --> Mixpanel Third Party framework installed using carthage
```

Each framework is setup as a project dependency of the one above it, in other words:
- CoreFramework contains the Mixpanel framework
- UIFramework has a dependency on CoreFramework
- The Main app has a dependency on the UIFramework

This structure is setup on a common workspace.

I can build and test each framework separately without any issues.
My issue comes down to accessing the CoreFramework from the main app.

If I grab my root view controller and write the following code:

```
import UIKit
import UIFramework

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let object = UIFrameworkClass()
        object.testFunction()
    }

}
```

The app runs and builds on device without any issues.
However, if I write this code:

```
import UIKit
import UIFramework
import CoreFramework

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let object = UIFrameworkClass()
        object.testFunction()

        coreFrameworkGlobalTestFunction()
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error when building:

```
Framework not found Mixpanel for architecture arm64
```

I've tried embedding and linking the Mixpanel framework directly to my app to no avail.

Any ideas on what's causing this? How can I access classes and functions on the CoreFramework from my main app without getting an error?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to add all these framework in your target's building phase-link section? Also try to clean and restart your xcode, it works sometimes.

Comment: Yes I have, restarting Xcode and cleaning the derived data folder yields the same results. :/

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else bumps into the same issue in the future: 
I was able to fix the problem by adding the path for the Mixpanel library to the `Frameworks Search Path` property of the Main App's `Build Settings` and the problem went away.

Gotta love some good ol' Xcode magic.

Comment: but wasn't the Mixpanel framework in the default search path?